# What counts as inline-svg

Tags: svg, d3.js, modernizr

I just learned that Modernizr uses two different classes for SVG support: no-svg and no-inlinesvg. I can't seem to understand the difference between the two.

According to caniuse.com, Safari 5 and below does not support inline SVG, but does support SVG. I tested this on some D3.js visualizations (them rendering SVG) and Safari 5 displays that correctly.

My first guess was that D3 produces inline SVG, but that does not seem to be the case. So I would love to hear an explanation of the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Inline SVG** means using `<svg>` (and child) tags directly in your html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <svg width="300px" height="300px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <text x="10" y="50" font-size="30">My SVG</text>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

**SVG Support** refers to the ability to understand and display SVG files using the `<embed>` or `<object>` tags.

Comment: Makes sense, but then how come (js-generated) inline SVG is viewable in Safari 5? For instance this: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/. And source for Safari 5 not supporting inline SVG is: http://caniuse.com/svg-html5.

Comment: Not sure, as I don't have Safari 5 around to test with.  Note that Safari `5.1+` as well as IOS Safari `5.0+`__does__ claim to support inline svg.